# Change a trendline type in Excel chart, based on cell value

Tags: excel, charts, trendline

I have a drop down menu in a cell, which takes two options - A and B.
I want to automatically update the trendline on a chart based on the value in this drop down menu cell, i.e.,

- if value of cell is A, then the chart to show Linear trendline
- if value of cell is B, then the cart to show Moving average trendline

I can't find a way to do that. If this is not possible, can I do it somehow with a macro function, i.e., when the value in  the cell is changed, then create new chart and show it on the same place?